# How to URL Redirect "www.example1.com" & "www.example2.com" & "example2.com" to "example1.com" in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, redirect

We are facing problems in URL Redirecting 4 URL's to a single URL.

The following is the mapping we need.

Entered URL       -> Target URL 
example1.com      -> example1.com 
www.example1.com  -> example1.com 
example2.com      -> example1.com 
www.example2.com  -> example1.com

We are using IIS7  on WIn Srv 2008 SP1.

We now have all the bindings set in IIS. We have HTTPS. But for only the Target URL option we are having a valid certificate. All the rest of the options are shown as "This Connection is Untrusted" and the user has to manually click on the proceed to website. We want to redirect the user to the desired site even if the user types any of the URL's. I mean the User's URL in the browser should change to the target URL and the secured connection should open.

I have found URL Redirect 2.0 after googling for this. Will this solve my problem. Is it safe or is there any gotcha's involved in this.

Any better option without installing any.

TIA

Arun Kumar Allu.

Comment: If your requirement is to reach the same web when user enters any of the above urls you could do that simply by adding them all to the same site under server bindings. Open IIS console > Right click on ur website > click on Edit bindings > in the SITE BINDINGS box > Add them all.

Comment: Thanx Indikaf, We have that already but for only the desired option we are having a valid certificate. All the rest of the options show as "This Connection is Untrusted" and the user has to manually click on the proceed to website. We want to redirect the user to the desired site even if the user types any of the URL's

Comment: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect. This gives how to do it using iis once the request is reached but as you said if it is untrusted I think you need to do it before request reaching your web server.

Comment: I tried that, but I guess it was falling in a loop and the web page never opened until I did an iisreset, after which the site opened with the targer URL. SO I am planning to use URL Redirect 2.0 for making a regex match for the other 3 and redirecting it to the tarhet URL. Doing this IIS redirection for the 1st time, so don't even know if this would work for me or not. Even need to take a go ahead signal from my seniors b4 installing the IIS addin. Will this work for me. Any Ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have IIS "URL Rewrite" module installed, if so, then use these rewrite rules:

```
<rule name="AllToExample1Http" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example1\.com$|^example2\.com$|^www\.example2\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example1.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="AllToExample1Https" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.example1\.com$|^example2\.com$|^www\.example2\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://example1.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanx Tomek, Can you please help me with what is this "{R:1}" in the action tag.
The following works fine for me but after 3-4 hours, the sub site does not open until I do an iisreset and then it works.

Comment: <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" exactDestination="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example1\.com$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example1.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

Comment: Now I have changed it to "<action type="Redirect" url="http://example1.com/{R:0}" >" and now it seems to be working fine, but I am not sure myself if this is the appropriate solution. Please confirm. TIA.

Comment: The changes which you've made will work providing that:  1. it's you intention to redirect any domain which is not `example1.com`  2. the request doesn't contain the `path` part, if it does you end up redirecting to `http://example1.comYourPath` (notice missing slash after host name), the `{R:0}` is equivalent to `{R:1}` in this particular case

Answer (score 1):

`<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="maintenance.htm" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" exactDestination="false" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example1\.com$" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://example1.com/{R:0}"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>`

Comment: Thanks every1 for the help. This did solve my issue.
The required configuration is already done to convert all http requests to https requests.